# "Fatal error: Class 'Google_Http_Request' not found in" while using Oauth2.0 authentication and Google Contact API for PHP

Tags: php, api, oauth

I am trying to retrieve all my contacts using Google Contact API. For this I used Oauth2.0 authentication and Google Contact API for PHP.

But i am getting this error:
"Fatal error: Class 'Google_Http_Request' not found in"

could not get the reason why. I even used Google_HttpRequest but error remains the same but this time it is for "Google_HttpRequest".

Code used is as follows, can some one help because for this this there no help is available on internet

```
<?php
//require_once 'C:/xampp/htdocs/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/Client.php';

require_once 'C:/xampp/htdocs/google-api-php-client-master/vendor/autoload.php';// or wherever autoload.php is located
session_start();
//Declare your Google Client ID, Google Client secret and Google redirect uri in  php variables
$google_client_id = 'xxx-yyy.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$google_client_secret = 'xxxx';
$google_redirect_uri = 'https://localhost:4433/xxx.php';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client -> setApplicationName('My application name');
$client -> setClientid($google_client_id);
$client -> setClientSecret($google_client_secret);
$client -> setRedirectUri($google_redirect_uri);
$client -> setAccessType('online');

$client->setApplicationName('Google Contacts PHP Sample');

$client->setScopes("http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/");

///if (isset($_GET['code'])) {

/// $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);

/// $auth_code = $_GET["code"];

/// $_SESSION['google_code'] = $auth_code;

/// header('Location: ' . $google_redirect_uri);

///}

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
$client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
$_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
$redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
$client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}
if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
unset($_SESSION['token']);
$client->revokeToken();
}

if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
//$req = new Google_Http_Request("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full", 'GET', null, null);   
$req = new Google_Http_Request("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full");
$val = $client->getIo()->authenticatedRequest($req);



// The contacts api only returns XML responses.
$response = json_encode(simplexml_load_string($val->getResponseBody()));
print "<pre>" . print_r(json_decode($response, true), true) . "</pre>";

// The access token may have been updated lazily.
$_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {
$auth = $client->createAuthUrl();
}

if (isset($auth)) {
print "<a class=login href='$auth'>Connect Me!</a>";
} else {
print "<a class=logout href='?logout'>Logout</a>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to mix things that cant be mixed.

The current [Google php client library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) which you are using only supports discovery service APIs.  Which are the new APIs that return Json.

The google contacts API is an older Gdata api which returns XML. the two do not speak the same language.  I haven't tried it but the old [GData](https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/php_client_lib) client library can be found here.

Comment: @DalmTo My aim is simply to retrieve all my contacts in GMAIL  using Google Contact API and Oauth2.0  can you please suggest which API to use ?

Comment: There is only one API you can use its the https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/reference.  But you are using the wrong client library.  You need to use the Gdata client library.

Comment: @Dalm from where I can download this library ?

Comment: @Dalm can't new API be used for retrieving contacts in GMAIL using and Oauth2.0.

Comment: There is no new API Google contacts API, v3 is the current API for Google contacts. Yes it can be accessed using Oauth2 this is the only way to Authenticate with it  to my knowledge.  I gave you the link to the Gdata client library in my answer https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/php_client_lib

Comment: I will just request if you could please give me the step wise approach to solve this requirement of mine. means how should i start?

Comment: Welcome to stack please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.   We can help you fix issues with your code which I have just explained to you why it wont work.   We do not give you step by step or write code for you.   Googleing "google contacts api php example" comes up with a large number of examples that should get you started if you have issues ask a new question with your errors.

Comment: Actually i have tried all the examples given on net but nothing worked, that is why i asked this question. code given above is one of them. problem actually is if someone can can just give a link to any sample code. rest i will do but what ever example i have tried were all in vain.

Comment: I know it might be stupid to ask this but can you please tel me what is the difference between "discovery service APIs" ,"Google php client library", "google contacts API"